# How to use functions.php as a mean to enable WP-PostRatings?

Tags: php, wordpress

It's long since I touched WP code. I recently started a website, and I want to use the WP-PostRatings good old rating plugin.

In [WP-PostRatings guide](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/) it says that you need to edit index.php, archive.php or any other page that you want to add ratings.

I was wondering if there is any way that I can add some code in functions.php to have the same effect?

The reason that I want to add code to functions.php is that I want to use the [Code Snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin to add the code. Thus, no need to change the code of the theme I am using. This gives me the flexibility to change the code, update the theme with no worries, and even change the theme in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. How you do it will depend on where you are trying to put the HTML output. You can use the `[ratings]` shortcode provided by the plugin if you want the output to show in an editable area. Otherwise, you'll have to use a hook or filter to modify the part of the page you are trying to put the output in.

Comment: Thanks. How shall I use the shortcode [ratings] in functions.php? Is it even possible to utilize funtions.php for this goal that I have?

Comment: It sounds like you wouldn't want to use the shortcode. You'd want to use the_ratings() in combination with a hook. See [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to understand hooks. It's one of the foundation skills of WP development.